# Multimedia configuration

Tags: 12.04, multimedia

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04.  Back in the day there was an article on Ubuntu about how to configure it for Multimedia support.  Is there anything like that now?  If so I can't find it.

Thanks,
--glenn

Answer (score 0):

Its an interesting question.

You may try ubuntu studio version 13.04 (Raring Ringtail )for multimedia.

This version still need to be tested.  You may check the following url:

http://ubuntustudio.org/2013/04/ubuntu-studio-13-04-raring-ringtail-release-candidates-needs-testing/